Preference Mapping using missing consumer data
I'm doing a preference mapping analysis using sensory and consumer liking data based on carto() function in R from SensoMineR package.
Structure

Sensory Data: Each row represents a product and columns the given scores for specific attributes for all products,
Consumer Data: Each row represents a product and columns the given overall liking scores for many consumers.

However my consumer data has missing cases due to the design as each consumer rates only 3 products. In this case there are many NAs populated in the dataset. and the carto function throws an error
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, missing, value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(MatH, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

I thought I can impute NAs for a given consumer using the mean of those 3 product liking scores. Is this a legit approach?
